# Can't generate javadoc in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

This really should be a stupid question, but I'm trying to generate javadoc in my Android eclipse project and I'm getting errors.  I'm on a mac and the javadoc command is set at

```
 /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javadoc
```

But for some reason it seems to be using 1.3

```
 annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
 (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
        @Override
```

Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: It's not using Java 1.3 (otherwise it wouldn't know about `-source 5`). It's simply set to parse Java code as being for Java 1.3 by default. Have you tried providing the switch `-source 5` to your `javadoc` call?

Comment: Generating in eclipse, can't find an option for that.

Comment: And for some reason doing this via command line tells me it can't find source files.  I'm running the command from a folder full of source files.

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse (Kepler release), go to Project -> Generate Javadoc..., then after the second "Next", you will see an option to select "JRE source compatibility". There, you have selected 1.3 (you have to select 1.5 or higher).